# Why was this answer audit low-quality?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I just failed [an audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/22745340) when reviewing and I don't see why this answer is low quality.  It had 2 downvotes (probably because the answer was wrong), but I don't see what was wrong with the answer.  I don't know PHP, SQL, or MariaDB, so I'm not 100% sure if it actually answered the question or not, and even if it wasn't a right answer, I have been told before that very low quality flags shouldn't be raised for incorrect information.  The answer said to go to a website as well, but that was in addition to the rest of the answer so I thought it was fine.  Do answers with code need an explanation?  Is it wrong to just post code in an answer and say nothing else?  Am I suffering at the hands of another bad audit?

Comment: Why are you making auditing decisions if you don't know for sure if it is good or bad? Why not simply skip it?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I thought that it *was* good.  Is it a better option to skip reviews if you don't understand the topic?

Comment: As I understand it, the whole basis for auditing is to use your expertise to help people who don't have the same knowledge and abilities. If you're not very sure, leave it alone. This is why you should apply filters so that you only audit what you feel confident in. This is why a skip link is present.

Comment: see also: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, this is a pretty borderline audit, as audits in First Posts tend to be... But here are a few things you could've observed:

1. The question (visible on the review page below the answer) is asking about the design of a MySQL-backed PHP app. The answer provides... Some basic examples of SQL syntax.
2. The question asks about implementing three operations: viewing (retrieving), editing (updating) and deleting records. The answer covers deleting, retrieving, and... adding new records. It appears the asker has already figured out how to add new records and is stuck on everything else.
3. The asker describes (vaguely) a schema involving multiple tables, where in order to render a given record the values in the editable table would need to be cross-referenced with the values in the definition table(s). The answer neither acknowledges, questions, or attempts to address this complexity.

In the answerer's defense, the question is a bit hairy. However, I think it's safe to say  that whatever advice they might have been seeking, they *weren't* after a bare-bones and incomplete demonstration of SQL syntax. In light of this, you could've...

- ...pointed this out to them via a comment
- ...downvoted
- ...flagged
- ...thrown up your hands in confusion and hit "Skip"

All these actions would've been appropriate to some degree. What is in no way appropriate  was "no action" - which happens to be the option that you chose.

Please remember: when you're reviewing in the First Posts queue, **each review is a chance to introduce new members to Stack Overflow**, to give them a warm welcome and/or much-needed advice and guidance. Not everyone *needs* a warm welcome or guidance, but... In this case, I think it's safe to say that some guidance was *badly* needed. Next time, either try to provide that guidance... Or skip the review and leave it for someone who can.

Comment: I agree with most of this, except... what about it really warranted a flag? It certainly seems like an attempt to answer the question, it's not quite very low quality, and it's *definitely* not spam or abusive. Which flag should be used on answers like this one?

Comment: @Pikachu I think any action except upvote and 'No Action Needed' will pass the audit, not just flagging.

Comment: @PikachuthePurpleWizard flag to delete.

Answer (score 13):

> I don't know PHP, SQL, or MariaDB, so I'm not 100% sure if it actually answered the question or not

Uh-oh. Sounds like you probably should have hit **Skip**.

> even if it wasn't a right answer, I have been told before that very low quality flags shouldn't be raised for incorrect information.

That's true. However, this wasn't deleted because it was incorrect, or because it didn't contain enough information to go along with the code. The presentation of the answer was actually fine.

The answer was deleted because it was ***irrelevant*** to the question that was asked. Notice that the question was about using PHP with **MySQL**. Notice next that the answer was about **MariaDB**. Those are two different databases, making the answer inapplicable to the question without *at least* some commentary indicating that the syntax in MariaDB is the same as that in MySQL, but the MariaDB manual is better (or whatever).

The only quibble here might be that the answer shouldn't have been flagged as "very low quality", but instead "not an answer". I'm just going to say, I don't lawyer about a distinction between those two flag types. They both mean "this answer needs to be deleted", and I process them accordingly. This doesn't affect what it would have taken for you to pass the audit, though.

Comment: I've never known when to use skip, is there a general guideline as to when one should use skip?

Comment: When you aren't sure, @Jodast. Like when the post is about technology you're unfamiliar with, or when you can't see why it might have been flagged.

Comment: If you're not... let's say, *80% certain* that you know which action to take... Hit skip. If you have to stop and question whether you even know what the post you're reviewing is talking about, hit skip. If you're bored and find yourself humming "the ants go marching two-by-two" instead of reading, hit skip - and then take a break and do something else for a while.

Comment: Okay, I was unclear as to when skipping is necessary because it leaves a post that might need attention unattended.

Comment: There are other reviewers. Skipping doesn't review it from the queue. It just skips it for you.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, Skipping makes the post immediately available for someone else to review, @Jodast - so it's really one of the best ways to make sure it gets attention when you're not sure. "No Action Needed", on the other hand, drops it out of the queue and... maybe nobody ever sees it again.

Comment: @Shog9 That actually really helps with my review process, I didn't know how reviews actually worked in terms of what happens after the review.

Comment: @CodyGray, why is the NAA flag appropriate here? I have very poor experience flagging technically incorrect answers, as this one is, as NAA. Usually I get the custom mod message that flags shouldn't be used on technically incorrect answers.

Comment: I'll second @Luuklag querying the suggestion of NAA. I know that Cody, in his pre-mod days, complained (as I have) about the inanity of our working definition of NAA (in which a post is only NAA if there is no imaginable on-topic question to which it could possibly be even a bad or incomplete answer, and NAA and VLQ flags should be strictly declined in all other circumstances), but as far as I know that policy - no matter how stupid and blatantly inconsistent with the description in the flag dialog - has not changed. As far as I see, a NAA flag would be likely to be declined here.

Comment: @CodyGray would you reason then that by the accepted comicaly representation of the NAA flag (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) This answer was an orange, and not an apple? I could agree to that, but experience learns that usually the outcome of the flag review doesn't resemble that.

Comment: A NAA flag was *not* declined here; I marked one as helpful, that's why it became an audit, @Mark. I process flags as a moderator with the same sanity that I'd want them to be processed with as a community member. I can't promise that other moderators will do the same, of course. There is naturally some inconsistency in how a bunch of human beings handle flags, so until they replace us all with robots, the community is going to have to suffer with that issue. Now, I still won't delete answers for being *incorrect*, just because I have no way to assess that.

Comment: But if the answer is clearly inapplicable to the question, such as because it is about a different programming language or framework, then yes, I will certainly delete it in response to a NAA flag. I believe *many* of the other moderators will do the same thing. (cc @Luuklag)